# Can I include a plain text file in xdocreport template

Tags: include, xdocreport

I'm using XDocReport and freemarker to create reports and want to include another template like this:

```
«[#include "template.ftl"]»
```

and get an exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.loadTemplate(TemplateCache.java:436)
```

I have already understood that it is not possible to include another odt or docx file.

Also I want to set the locale in the Freemarker Configuration but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wish to use #include to merge several template docx but XDocReport doesn't support #include. Merging docx is a very hard task.